# Ruby process: broken /proc/self/environ

Tags: ruby, environment-variables, systemd

There is a really strange situation in my Ruby-based processes: their `/proc/self/environ` is really broken. For some reason, the `ENV` inside Ruby looks fine but I'd like to understand what's going on.

Processes are started using `bundle exec`, for example `bundle exec sidekiq`. The end result is that the `/proc/<pid>/environ` file only contains a couple of bytes (usually 4) of the invoked command plus a bunch of zeroes. In the example above, the `environ` file would look like

```
$ sudo hexdump -C /proc/2613895/environ
00000000  65 6b 69 71 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |ekiq............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000390  00 00 00 00 00 00 00                              |.......|
00000397
```

When invoking another command line, for example a `rake` task, the `environ` file would contain the last couple of characters of the rake task name.

Since the environ file cannot be modified by the process itself after it starts, it must have been set by whomever made the `execve` call but I am stupefied who might be responsible and why.

This seems to mostly happen when processes are started through systemd, but none of the other processes started by systemd show the same behaviour; only the ones started through `bundle exec` so I'm thinking that it's not related to systemd.

Comment: The same appears to occur with the nginx webserver, at least in version 1.18.0!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The */proc/$pid/environ* file normally only contains the environment passed to the process when it was created. It does not reflect any changes to its environment the process may have made after it began execution. Furthermore, it simply exposes the portion of the stack of the process which contained the original env vars. If the process modifies those stack locations that will be reflected in the content of that procfs file. See, for example, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302948/change-proc-pid-environ-after-process-start.

I would complain to the Ruby team since they shouldn't be stomping on the original env var stack locations.

Comment: Thank you! My confusion mostly resulted from the fact that the documentation states that it cannot be changed and I never observed such a thing. It's still not clear why this doesn't happen all the time (i.e. mostly when launching via systemd, rarely when launching via CLI), though. But if it can be modified by the process, then I probably have to look inside of the process again, not outside.